# Git squashing commits with sensitive data

Tags: git

let me say that I have commits like:

A-B-C-D-E-F-G

commit B contains some passwords (and some code changes)
in commit G there are removed passwordes (added in B), and now they are readen from external files

so now in G there is no password but if someone will look into history he may see sensitive data from commit B.

Can i do something with it using git rebase or some another tool?

Comment: Yes. You can rewrite history in git. As long as you control every clone of the repository, that is.
But it will be far more effective to simply **change passwords** and get over it.

Comment: @Tomek, I think your comment **is** the answer, you should post it.

Comment: Yes it seems that this will do the thing, rebasing and filtering branches may cause unexpected behaviours

Comment: @Benjol Well? OK. Posting it, unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can rewrite history in git. As long as you control every clone of the repository, that is.

But it will be far more effective to simply **change passwords** and get over it.